# 1k vs 4k texture resolution performance impact

Tags: opengl, graphics, directx, game-engine

This is for realtime graphics.

Let's say that there is a single mesh that we are rendering. We place a 1k (1024x1024) texture on it and it renders fine. Now let's say that we place a 4k texture on it but render only a 1k section of the texture by using different UVs on the same mesh.

Now both times, the visible surface has 1k texture on it. But one comes from 1k texture map the other from 4k texture map. Would there be a difference in **performance**, not counting increased VRAM usage from 4k map.

Comment: For any non-ancient desktop GPU, I would not expect a noticable difference. But as always: you should benchmark/profile it on all relevant target architectures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For all intents and purposes, no, there will be no difference.

By restricting the UVs to the top left 1024x1024 you'll be pulling in the same amount of texture data as if the texture were 1024x1024 and you read the entire thing. The number of texture samples remains the same as well.

It's impossible to rule it out completely of course without having low-level knowledge of every GPU past, present and future, but you should assume the performance will be the same.